# Container Inset box-shadow over child image

Tags: css, image, parent

I have a container which holds a child image, and that container has a scrollable overflow. I'm trying to add an inset box-shadow which overlays the image to give the impression that the image is set behind a frame. I'm running into a bunch of issues though. Using a :after pseudo element, I am able to achieve the overlay I want, however, the box-shadow itself ends up having a scrollable overflow as well. That is to say, when I scroll the image, the box shadow will also scroll, resulting in the container border hiding the box-shadow. How would I go about fixing this so that the box-shadow maintains it's positioning when scrolling?

```css
.map-container {
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        height: 600px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    .map-container::after {
        box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 10px #888888;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
       <img id="map" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/800/800" alt="map" height="800px">
    </div>
```

UPDATE 1:
I think I've figured out a workaround!

I've wrapped both the container and the image in a new parent div for just the box shadow. I've changed the z-index of the image itself to -1 and changed it's position to relative This gets me a box shadow that does not scroll into the overflow. This did however cause an issue where the scroll bar is inside the confines of the box-shadow. To move the scroll bar to the outside, I changed margin-right of the container to -20px.

```html
 <div id="map_shadow">
       <div class="map-container">
          <img id="map" src="img/pub_map.png" alt="map" height="800px">
       </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.map-container {
    margin-right: -20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#map {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

#map_shadow {
    margin: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 10px #888888;
}
```

Things I've tried:

> Played around with absolute positioning as well as Z-index to no avail.

> Tried getting rid of the image div and instead adding the image as the background-image of the container, but this seems to prevent scrollable overflow and messes with the aspect ratio in such a way that is not workable.

> Tried creating a separate "shadow" div within the parent container with intent to have it overlay the image. This works but this results in the same issue where the box-shadow still scrolls.

> Attempted adding an inset box-shadow to the image itself, but the image just overlays it.

> Getting rid of the overflow and decreasing the height of the image is not an option, as parts of the image then become too small to be legible.